# ServiceActivationException because of bindingConfiguration attribute

Tags: wcf, exception, https

I want to be able to access the service using both http and https

On endpoint at address "secure", If I include the bindingConfiguration attribute, I get a ServiceActivationException.

But if I remove the bindingConfiguration="webBindingSecure", all works well. What is the problem with the bindingConfiguration?

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="OperatorApp.Api" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="secure" binding="webHttpBinding" **bindingConfiguration="webBindingSecure"**  contract="OperatorApp.IApi" behaviorConfiguration="ssl" />

  <endpoint address="normal" binding="webHttpBinding"   contract="OperatorApp.IApi" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  httpsGetEnabled="true" >
     </serviceMetadata>
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  <behavior name="ssl">
    <webHttp/>
  </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webBindingSecure">
      <security mode="Transport">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Looking at [`<security> of <webHttpBinding>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924478.aspx) it appears you need to set the `<transport clientCredentialType="...." />` child element of the <`security>` element when using security mode="Transport".

Comment: I did it an it doesn't help. Can I somehow get more information on what the problem is?